# Display an Array of User Data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to Javascript and have been stuck on an issue. I've built a random card generator that works with an API. The generator takes in a user's dilemma, draws a random solution card and saves the pairing. However I'm having trouble displaying the pairing in a databox below. Here's the relevant code and a picture of the generator for reference.

```
let dataStore = []

let dilemma = "";
    strategy = "";

function saveData() {
    newPair = {dilemma: userText.value, strategy: cardText.innerText};
    dataStore.push( newPair )
    displayData();
}

function doSmtElse( element ) {
 
    console.log( "element is here : " , element , element.dilemma , element.strategy)
 

    for (let i = 0; i < dataStore.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {break;}
        const element = dataStore[i];
        doSmtElse(element )
    }
}

function displayData() {
 
    console.log( "dataStore is here : " , dataStore)
 

    for (let index = 0; index < dataStore.length; index++) {
        const element = dataStore[index];
        doSmtElse(element )
    }
}
```

[Picture of generator + console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnTJ9.png)

Answer (score -1):

For the ticket system you should use a class to hold the data and add / remove it.

displayData shows how to create the elements from the array data and add them to the DOM.

Your question has no example of the html, so I just made my own.

```js
// making a ticket system class to handle stuff related to tickets.
class TicketSystem {
  // constructor function is ran when the class is called.
  constructor() {
    this.tickets = [];
  }

  // made class method to add a new ticket object to tickets array.
  add({ problem, solution }){
    this.tickets.push({
      problem,
      solution
    });
  }
}

// making a new ticket system
const ticket = new TicketSystem();

// adding a click event to the add button, so when you click it it adds the ticket to the ticket system and re-renders the DOM.
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => saveData());

function saveData() {
  // using add method to add new ticker.
  ticket.add({
    // selecting the value of the element with id of problem;
    problem: document.querySelector("#problem").value,
    // selecting the value of the element with id of solution;
    solution: document.querySelector("#solution").value,
  })
  // rerendering the ticket list in the DOM
  displayData();
}

// loops through the tickets and adds them to dom.
function displayData() {
  // selecting element with id of tickets
  const parent = document.querySelector("#tickets");
  // clearing it so it has noting inside.
  // do this so we don't have duplicate data.
  parent.innerHTML = "";
  
  // looping through each ticket in the ticket system.
  ticket.tickets.forEach(t => {
    // making a new div element.
    const elm = document.createElement("div");
    // giving it a class of ticket
    elm.classList.add("ticket");
    
    // making a new div element.
    const prob = document.createElement("div");
    // giving it a class of problem
    prob.classList.add("problem");
    //setting it's text value to the current tickets problem;
    prob.textContent = t.problem;
    
    // making a new div element.
    const solu = document.createElement("div");
    // giving it a class of solution
    solu.classList.add("solution");
    //setting it's text value to the current tickets solution;
    solu.textContent = t.solution;
    
    // adding the problem and solution div to the ticket div.
    elm.appendChild(prob);
    elm.appendChild(solu);
    
    // adding the ticket div to the tickets div.
    parent.appendChild(elm);
  });
}

saveData();
```

```css
.ticket {
  text-align: center;
}

.problem {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.solution {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="problem" type="text" value="No Food"></input>
<input id="solution" type="text" value="Go to supermarket"></input>
<button>ADD</button>
<div id="tickets"></div>
```

Comment: i don't think this is responding to my question :-/

Comment: You want it to appear in the saved info section?

Comment: `I'm having trouble displaying the pairing in a databox below.` That's what my example does in the displayData function. The question doesn't give much info so I made mine from scratch.

Comment: @invizi that definitely went over my head, i see how it relates now

Comment: I'll add comments to my code if it's too hard to follow.

Comment: that'd help, i'm very new to this. my only issue is that I believe my own code to be very close-- I'm getting the proper key: value pairs when i console.log but its printing out "undefined" on the page. I think I'm only a few lines away but can't seem to get there

Comment: Added the comments. Hopefully that's usefull.

Comment: just saw that, i'll take a look. i really appreciate the assistance